# Plotly Dash Server on Heroku fails on Push - bonjour-py==0.3

Tags: python, heroku, bonjour, plotly-dash, pybonjour

I am trying to deploy a Dash App (from Plot.ly) using a heroku server.

  **-  tutorial used found here: https://dash.plot.ly/deployment**
First, I signed into my heroku account and created the app:

```
heroku create [app-name]
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial app boilerplate'
```

Then, when I went to push, this error message occured:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_fa37b18f035bde634151755000947df0/requirements.txt
```

I have tried removing bonjour-py==0.3 from the requirements file with no luck. I have also tried removing the requirements file. Not sure what is wrong.